# how to register for website like campl.us did?

Tags: web, dns, registration

It's hard to find a domain name that's not grabbed by someone else yet. So we are thinking about registering something like camera+ has - campl.us, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Run a google search for the TLD in question.  You can usually purchase them through a common registrar but occasionally, you have to go through the country's own page.

Comment: this may not be related to TLD

Comment: TLD: Top-Level Domain (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)

Comment: let me give another example, for Instagram, the domain name of it's site is instagr.am, is it a TLD?

Comment: In that example, the TLD is ".am," and it represents the TLD of the country Armenia.  If you go to a registrar like godaddy.com or namecheap.com, you can buy a handful of them just like you would a ".com" or a ".org".  Some of the more obscure ones (like ".st") require you to purchase the domain directly from the country itself, instead of through a 3rd party distributing registrar.

List of all TLD's: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: Are you not satisfied with the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking about is in reference to Top-Level Domain Names.  You can find a selection of choices for Top-Level Domains by visiting 3rd party registrars like [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com) or [NameCheap](http://www.namecheap.com).  However, if you'd like to purchase a more obscure domain name (like ".st"), the best thing to do is just run a search for it on Google with the words "domain purchase" appended.  You'll either be presented with the country's personal TLD registration page, or you'll find that you can't actually buy it.

Resources:

- List of Top-Level Domains: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains
- Example of individual country's registration page (Sao Tome - ".st"): http://www.nic.st/